# Is there a way to force updating the size of the non-active child of QStackedWidget when it's resized?

Tags: qt

I have a QStackedWidget (QSW) with 2 child components, both are configured to expand to the size of their parents.

One of the child components (CC) resizes its content based on CC's size. These 
calculated sizes are also used to determine the size of components which are always visible in a sibling of QSW. In order for these sizes to be always correct, CC needs to be resized even when it's not the active component in QSW.

What's the most straightforward way to accomplish this?

Edit: CC's sizePolicy is MinimumExpanding/MinimumExpanding, so the requirement is that CC's size is set to expand to the maximum size QSW allows it to, even when CC is not the active component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a QStackedLayout with the StackAll stacking mode solves the issue. When the stacking mode is set to StackAll, all child widgets are showing, they just cover each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fine matter of whether or not the size hint works and what size policy is. In such cases the call of [QWdiget::adjustSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#adjustSize) is usually helping but to answer with confidence more context of your code is needed. Anyway, the docs say when it helps. I would trap the moment when the size is not correct and apply adjustSize. Mind that the scope where you apply adjustSize matters too.